# Can we execute seeder without truncating table or is there any way to achieve this

Tags: php, laravel, yii2, migration, php-7

we are working on a project where I would like to insert one row to database using seeder but when I have executed that seeder it truncates table and insert seeds record. What I want is it should insert a new record only without truncating existing data.

Can anyone help to get this?

This seeder feature is available in mostly all MVC like Laravel and Yii2 that we are using.

```
use yii\db\Migration;

class m200118_113041_create_table_admin_master extends Migration
{

    public function Safeup()
    {
        $seeder = new \tebazil\yii2seeder\Seeder();
        $generator = $seeder->getGeneratorConfigurator();
        $faker = $generator->getFakerConfigurator();

        $seeder->table('admin_master')->columns([
            'email'=>$faker->email,
            'password'=>rand(1, 999999),
            'created_date'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ])->rowQuantity(30);
        $seeder->refill();

    }

    public function Safedown()
    {
        // $this->dropTable('{{%admin_master}}');
    }
}
```

Here above is the example of my migration in Yii2

Comment: Share your seeder code

Comment: @Komal I have updated my question with my comment.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a new migration file and put insert query in that easily

```
php artisan make:migration insert_somename_table
```

than inside migration file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use DB;

class InsertSomenameTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        DB::('somename')->insert(array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2'));
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        DB::('somename')->where('key1', '=', 'value1')->delete();
    }
}
```

and execute

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Above commands are insert queries which has not used any seeder concept

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways

1.**Update your seeder**

Consider your table name is 'categories' and you already have 12 categories.

You should start your new category id from 13 in the seeder array.

Your seeder look like this

```
public function run()
{
        $data = array(
            ['id' => 13, 'category' => 'Category1', 'status' => 1],
            ['id' => 24, 'category' => 'category2', 'status' => 1]
        );

        DB::table('categories')->insert($data);
}
```

2. **Execute queries**

Write one method and execute insert queries

Comment: Above commands are insert queries which has not used any seeder concept

Comment: Yes, I am just giving you other solution